# How to see/determine on disk file size on Linux?

Tags: files, linux-mint, disk-usage

On windows you can see the size actual size of a file/directory and the size on disk, this size on disk depends on block size.

How can I see this on Linux (mint)?

I have disk with thousands of pictures with varied sizes.

I want to see their actual size and the space they take up on disk, especially directories. On windows the difference can be in gigabytes of wasted space.

Comment: Do you plan on recreating your filesystem(s) based on the results, in order to reduce this wasted space? Otherwise, it's a fact of life for most filesystems.

Comment: yes that is what i wanted, to reduce wasted space or even just make two partition with different block sizes, one for video and another for images. because I like the video playback benefits of having huge block sizes(or is it just a placebo effect).

Comment: What do you mean by "especially directories" ? You want the size of the directory node itself, or the size of all the files contained in the directory ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `du`. Executing `du -s <directory>` shows you much disk space a directory's contents use up. `du` can also count the sizes of each file in the directory individually and tell you how big their total content is:

`du -s --apparent-size <directory>`

If you want to know the amount of "wasted" space resulting from allocation in blocks, just subtract the second command's result from the first's.

Note: `--apparent-size` reports the size in kilobytes. You can use the `-b` flag instead, if you want to know the exact number of bytes a file contains. This is useful if you want to know how many bytes (without headers and such) you would need to send over the network to deliver the file, for example.

Comment: Thank you. **du** is what I was looking for.
The combo.
`du -sh <directory>` for space on disk
`du -b <directory>` for actual size

Comment: `du -sb --apparent-size filename` returns exactly the same number as Windows's Properties Dialog's "Size (... bytes)".

Comment: On my RasPi, the file browser PCManFM displays discrepancies in files size on disk and actual of a factor of ten. However, `du` with and without `--apparent-size` displays the same number. Not sure who's lying.

Answer (score 0):

size on disk:

```bsh
du -s -B 1 *
du -s -B 1 * | cut -f 1
```

size of contents:

```bsh
du -s --apparent-size -B 1 *
du -s --apparent-size -B 1 * | cut -f 1
```

`-s` don't print sub-directories
`-B 1` print size in bytes instead of how many 1kb

`cut -f 1` omits the filename from output

---

here's a script that outputs:
`size of contents:xxxxx, size on disk: xxxxx, percentage wasted: xx.xx%, difference: xxxxx`

```
dirName='.';
sizeOfContents=$(du -s --apparent-size -B 1 "$dirName" | cut -f 1);
sizeOnDisk=$(du -s -B 1 "$dirName" | cut -f 1);
echo size of contents:$sizeOfContents, size on disk: $sizeOnDisk, percentage wasted: $(echo "scale=2 ; 100 - 100*$sizeOfContents/$sizeOnDisk" | bc)%, difference: $(($sizeOnDisk-$sizeOfContents));
```

one line version:

```
dirName='.'; sizeOfContents=$(du -s --apparent-size -B 1 "$dirName" | cut -f 1);sizeOnDisk=$(du -s -B 1 "$dirName" | cut -f 1);echo size of contents:$sizeOfContents, size on disk: $sizeOnDisk, percentage wasted: $(echo "scale=2 ; 100 - 100*$sizeOfContents/$sizeOnDisk" | bc)%, difference: $(($sizeOnDisk-$sizeOfContents));
```